# AWS/Strongswan-Ubuntu Site to Site Tunnel Cannot Ping Remote

Tags: amazon-web-services, routing, ipsec, ubuntu-18.04, strongswan

Ubuntu (Linode) Strongswan 5.6.2 Connecting to AWS (site to site).

1. I can ping from AWS endpoint to Ubuntu VPN.
2. I cannot ping from AWS endpoint to Ubuntu endpoint.
3. I cannot ping from Ubuntu VPN to AWS anything.

Ubuntu (VPN) public: 1.2.3.4  | Ubuntu (VPN) private: 192.168.234.113/24

AWS (VPN) public: 4.5.6.7 | AWS (VPN) private: 169.254.177.44/30

AWS (endpoint) private: 10.11.1.197

Ubuntu (endpoint) private: 192.168.136.15

I can ping the tunnel adapter's 169.254.177.46 from ubuntu (local), but not the remote
169.254.177.45 which I assume is the customer gateway (destination host unreachable)

```
root@ubuntu:~# ping 10.11.1.197
PING 10.11.1.197 (10.11.1.197) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 169.254.177.46 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 169.254.177.46 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
```

ip a

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f2:3c:93:db:4d:c0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 1.2.3.4/24 brd 194.195.211.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.234.113/17 brd 192.168.255.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 2600:3c02::f03c:93ff:fedb:4dc0/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute
       valid_lft 60sec preferred_lft 20sec
    inet6 fe80::f03c:93ff:fedb:4dc0/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: ip_vti0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1480 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ipip 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
6: Tunnel1@NONE: <POINTOPOINT,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1419 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ipip 1.2.3.4 peer 4.5.6.7
    inet 169.254.177.46 peer 169.254.177.45/30 scope global Tunnel1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::200:5efe:c2c3:d3cb/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

routes

```
10.11.1.0              0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 Tunnel1
169.254.177.44  0.0.0.0         255.255.255.252 U     0      0        0 Tunnel1
192.168.128.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.128.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
194.195.211.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

xfrm policy

```
src 192.168.128.0/17 dst 0.0.0.0/0
        dir out priority 391295
        mark 0x64/0xffffffff
        tmpl src 1.2.3.4 dst 4.5.6.7
                proto esp spi 0xcdecfff9 reqid 1 mode tunnel
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 192.168.128.0/17
        dir fwd priority 391295
        mark 0x64/0xffffffff
        tmpl src 4.5.6.7 dst 1.2.3.4
                proto esp reqid 1 mode tunnel
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 192.168.128.0/17
        dir in priority 391295
        mark 0x64/0xffffffff
        tmpl src 4.5.6.7 dst 1.2.3.4
                proto esp reqid 1 mode tunnel
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0
        socket in priority 0
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0
        socket out priority 0
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0
        socket in priority 0
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0
        socket out priority 0
src ::/0 dst ::/0
        socket in priority 0
src ::/0 dst ::/0
        socket out priority 0
src ::/0 dst ::/0
        socket in priority 0
src ::/0 dst ::/0
        socket out priority 0
```

Answer (score 1):

When I set up a site-to-site VPN I had similar strange issues. Some things to check that may help:

1. Check if route propagation is enabled on subnets and endpoints in AWS.
2. Check security groups and NACLs.
3. If you're trying to ping an EC2 instance, check security groups on that allow ping
4. If in doubt - draw a diagram of the connection from on-prem host to VPN to AWS, and check each step and direction.

I think I also used [this page](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/vpn-tunnel-troubleshooting/) and [this other page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/latest/s2svpn/HowToTestEndToEnd_Linux.html) - if you're trying to make it as secure as possible, probably best to start with less-secure until you've ironed out the wrinkles!